# DialogFragment with no title shrinks dialog width

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, material-design

The goal is to create a dialog that shows a list of files.

The problem is that once I remove the title (by any means including window feature, setting style, using styles.xml...) the dialog window converts to wrap_content constraint.

No property I set in layout influences this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_files_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_files_title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextActive"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_files_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my java code

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_files, null);

        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        recursiveScan(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_files_recycler_view);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        AdapterFiles adapter = new AdapterFiles(getActivity(), paths);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;

    }
```

The result is this

[image: dialog]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue seems to be when using `LinearLayout` as a root layout. I switched to `RelativeLayout` everything fit into place. Maybe this is a bug when using `LinearLayout` as a root layout in dialogs and removing title?

Comment: IDK about root layouts, but what I do to get a good dialog is creating new `AlertDialog` in `onCreateDialog()` and setting custom View as `setView()` on the dialog, and not creating the View in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @Yaroslav Mytkalyk I avoid using AlertDialog, because I need to customize the appearance and position of buttons. But I guess its just individual practice.

Comment: AlertDialog has style attributes that that control it's dimensions. Anyway, you can still use AlertDialog by adding buttons in your Dialog View instead of adding them as `setPositiveButton` in Dialog Builder.

Comment: Absolutely correct. This happens with a Linear Layout as parent in the `your_dialog_layout.xml`. PS- I came across this issue years back. And then again came across this today but forgot how I happened to resolved that in the past. You reminded me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

Window window = dialog.getWindow();

if (window != null) {
      window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

return dialog;
```

Try this out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please explain why do you declare LayoutParams and do not use them.